# How to prevent Entity Framework Core from logging SQL queries to Visual Studio Output while debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, logging, entity-framework-core

I'm debugging a program that processes batches of records. It is being slowed down noticeably by Entity Framework dumping SQL queries to Visual Studio Output. How do I stop that?

Here's what I've tried without success:

- settings

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database": "Warning",
        "Microsoft": "Warning"
    }
  }
```

This stopped it from logging to console, but not from logging to VS Output.

- trying to pass a dummy empty logger to the context:

```
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(
                options =>
                {
                    options.LogTo((x) => { });
```

- running the project in Release mode - even this does not prevent EF from dumping SQL queries.

The project is a .NET6 web application.

Comment: EF Core doesn't dump queries by default. It's *not* meant for batch processing either. Even if by `Visual Studio Output` you mean the Debug Window, [that needs to be configured](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/extensions-logging?tabs=v3). `LogTo` is an alternative way to log queries during development and won't affect ILogger configuration

Comment: Post your code, including the DbContext, its configuration, any interceptors and the logging configuration.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, it is `Debug -> Windows -> Output` window that I want to stop from dumping SQL queries. EF seems to be dumping queries there, even if I turn all the loggers I know off. It would be great to know the exact place where EF can be configured to not dump queries to VS output, both for performance and to avoid the "output noise" when looking for other messages.

Comment: That's the debugger's output, not the console or any logger's output. It's only generated when a debugger is attached. It shows the results of `Debug....` statements and doesn't affect even debug builds unless a debugger is attached

Comment: There's no impact on noise or performance unless a debugger is attached. The Debug Window already shows "noisy" stuff like threads starting and ending, which never appear in any logs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok, so EF debug output cannot be turned off while debugging? I know it won't affect the final performance, it's just the performance while debugging - I have to wait too long for the data to reach the state I need every time when I debug a few specific and tricky to reproduce cases.

Comment: Having the same problem. There doesn't seem to be a way to disable the spammy EF logging that goes straight to the Debug console. Somewhere in the framework there must be a bunch of `Debug.WriteLine` statements and it'd be very nice to be able to turn this off.

Comment: @JustAMartin I can gladly report that this bug will be fixed in an upcoming release. See https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/31694#issuecomment-1719623043